# Why metallic surface always becomes dark/black on diffuse baking on cycles engine?

Tags: baking

I have a material with node PRINCIPLE BSDF that sets mettalic to 1 and the color yellow but when baked always resulted black surface.

If set to 0, than the color yellow can appear.

So, the higher of the mettalic value it gets, the darker or blacker the baking result becomes. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no diffuse component to metallic Principled.  At 1.0, there is only a specular (glossy) component.  Between 0 and 1, it is mixed with the base Principled, which has a diffuse component.  If you want the metallic color, you should be baking glossy color instead of diffuse.  Baking lighting into a glossy shader isn't going to work very well, because it is view dependent (not sure exactly how Blender currently handles baking specular lighting, but not well, last time I looked.)